# Simple optimization in a SQL join

Tags: sql, join

Take the following simple SQL. It pulls any set of fields from two tables. A "Jobs" table, and some supporting table that we join off of the jobs table to get. Note that it's a left join because in this case the supporting table data is not required to be there.

```
select [fields]
from jobs j
left join supporting_data sd on sd.id = j.supporting_data_id
```

Would the query perform any different when written as follows:

```
select [fields]
from jobs j
left join supporting_data sd 
    on (j.supporting_data_id > 0) and (sd.id = j.supporting_id)
```

The difference being that if the main table has a record of "-1" which I commonly see in databases indicating "no value" then boolean short circuit evaluation should kick in and stop the query from checking the "supporting_data" table at all for that record.

Of course there should always be an index on the field. But if I had a record with "jobs.supporting_id = -1" then wouldn't this cause the database engine to scan the index for that record? Maybe negligible... Just wondering if there is any difference internally.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realize it would matter too much. I use Firebird RDBMS as well as MS SQL Server.

Comment: It looks like your table design is backwards. I'd expect the subordinate table (`supporting_data`) to keep a column the id of it's parent (`jobs_id`), rather than vice versa, as you have here.

Comment: Also: using NULL's rather than -1 to mean "No supporting data" can help performance for this kind of thing.

Comment: Don't think of parent-child relationships like INVOICE and INVOICE_LINES. Think of something like JOB and REFERRED_BY. I have a set of X possible referrals to get a job. Each job can map to one and only one possible source of a referrak

Comment: Also: using NULLs rather than -1 to mean "No supporting data" is more correct and standard.

Comment: On the NULL comments, I fully agree, but am not about to seek permission to overhaul the entire database :-)

Comment: There are too many variable factors to be certain. I would expect the answer would be: *Yes, perhaps*. But you would have to do some testing to confirm it. Some database optimizers can perform quite complex analysis. On the other hand, if there isn't a lot of data it may be equally performant to read it all, join it, and deliver the result. And if the two statements perform equally well, the first statement is more obvious and doesn't rely on embedded properties of the data.

Comment: The referal is still a subordinate table, and so should have the id for the parent.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No it shouldn't. Another example: Say my referrals are "Google", "Yellow Pages" and "Mail flyer". I have 1000 jobs. Each job has a "Referral" field pointing to one of 3 IDs from the referral table.